# Equivalence between Representations

Tags: representation-theory

Asseume that $k$ is an algebraically closed field of a strictly positive characteristic $p$, G is a finite group of order $p$ and that $p:G \rightarrow GL(V)$ is a representation of $G$. Then $p(g)$ is conjugate with an upper triangular matrix with ones along the diagonal. How do we prove the latter?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For any $g\in G$ you have $g^p=e$ in $G$, so $$0 = \rho(g^p) - \text{id} = \rho(g)^p - \text{id} = (\rho(g) - \text{id})^p.$$ In particular, $\rho(g) - \text{id}$ is nilpotent. What do you know about normal forms for nilpotent endomorphisms?

*Hint:* For any nilpotent endomorphism $f$, consider the increasing sequence $\ker(f)\subset\ker(f^2)\subset\ldots$ to build a basis with respect to which $f$ has the desired strictly upper triangular form.

Comment: not too much to be honest. however, i found the above in a book from Cambpell, Wehlau "Modular Invariant Theory" pg. 59. They prove the above inductively. But there is something in the proof which i don't understand

Comment: They refer the following : "We will construct an ordered basis of $V$ with respect to which every element of $G$ is lower triangular". I can't see why there does exist this basis in every $n$-dimensional vector space.

Comment: @mayer_vietoris I added a hint